# Re-factorize a program using single responsibility principle - SOLID- SRP

Tags: c#, object-oriented

The class `WalkingData` storages a "date" and a "walked distance". The class also read the stored data.

```
 public class WalkingData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int WalkedDistance { get; set; }
        private string _filePath = @"c:\Data\Json.txt";

        //Read Data from Json File
        public List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            //If file does not exist returns an empty list
            if (!File.Exists(_filePath)) return new List<WalkingData>();

            string jsonData;

            //Read the existing Json file
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_filePath))
            {
                jsonData = readtext.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Deserialize the Json and returs a list of WalkingData
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WalkingData>>(jsonData);            
        }

        //save an instance of  WalkingData in Json file
        public void Save()
        {
            List<WalkingData> lstExistingWalkingData = new List<WalkingData>();

            //if existing data, load it into lstExistingWalkingData
            if (File.Exists(_filePath))
                lstExistingWalkingData = GetAll();

            //Add the current instace into lstExistingWalkingData
            lstExistingWalkingData.Add(this);

            //Serialize lstExistingWalkingData
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstExistingWalkingData);

            //Save the Json file
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_filePath))
            {
                w.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }      
    }
```

After I applied the Single Responsibility Principle  I have the new code that I would like to confirm if I applied the principle in a reasonable way:

```
//This class is located on a library called BOL and has a reference to DAL library
    public class WalkingData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int WalkedDistance { get; set; }
    }

    //This class is located on a library called BOL and has a reference to DAL library
    public class WalkingDataManager
    {        
        WalkingDataRepository walkingDataRepository = new WalkingDataRepository();

        public List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            return walkingDataRepository.GetAll();
        }

        public void Save(WalkingData walkingData)
        {
            walkingDataRepository.Save(walkingData);
        }
    }

    //this class is located in library Called DAL
    internal class WalkingDataRepository
    {
        private string _filePath = @"c:\Data\Json.txt";

        //Read Data from Json File
        internal List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            //If file does not exist returns an empty list
            if (!File.Exists(_filePath)) return new List<WalkingData>();

            string jsonData;

            //Read the existing Json file
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_filePath))
            {
                jsonData = readtext.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Deserialize the Json and returs a list of WalkingData
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WalkingData>>(jsonData);
        }

        //save an instance of  WalkingData in Json file
        internal void Save(WalkingData walkingData)
        {
            List<WalkingData> lstExistingWalkingData = new List<WalkingData>();

            //if existing data, load it into lstExistingWalkingData
            if (File.Exists(_filePath))
                lstExistingWalkingData = GetAll();

            //Add the current instace into lstExistingWalkingData
            lstExistingWalkingData.Add(walkingData);

            //Serialize lstExistingWalkingData
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstExistingWalkingData);

            //Save the Json file
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_filePath))
            {
                w.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, where we review working code from one of your projects and provide suggestions on how that code can be improved. Unfortunately we can't help you re-write / refactor code. If you write a solution that separates the CRUD from the rest of the class we will be happy to review that code and tell you what you might improve.

Comment: I made the re-factorization, can you please confirm if the new code has applied the SRP?

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 9 times out of 10, "Manager" classes are named so because you couldn't think of a name for "this thing that does some work". Try defining the responsibility of the class better and finding a better name.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I think this basically boils down to a request for review of the second piece of code. The validation part is a bit off, but I imagine one of the answers could identify whether this code can be improved SRP-wise or not.

Comment: Can you please verify you've tested this code? Does it produce the correct output?

Comment: If you violate IoC, you violate SRP. You violate IoC. Also how is the manager different from the repo? They seem to do exactly the same...

Comment: "classes located on some library": If this is code *not* under your control and included for completeness, only, please a) properly attribute (hyperlink for reference welcome) b) present as a block quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 classes now follow the SRP.

You may want to allow the file path to be updated by a parameter passed into the WalkingDataRepository constructor. This would allow a user to set the file path by command line arguments, question and answer at runtime or environment variable.